# Layout no AlertDialog

Tags: android, layout, alertdialog

Tenho esse `AlertDialog` que mostra na tela outro *layout* , nesse *layout* tem varias `EditText` e um `Button`. Queria sabre como posso fazer para conseguir o *text* de cada umas das `edittext` quando eu clicar em `ok` ou no botão que tem no *layout* que vai aparecer no `AlertDialog`. Tentei fazer com `LayoutInflanter` mas não consegui. Vejam:

```
Context context = getBaseContext();
LayoutInflater inflant = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflant.inflate(R.layout.main, null);

AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

dialogo.setTitle("Informe o Nome");
dialogo.setView(R.layout.main);
dialogo.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int e) {
        ettext = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.ettext);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ettext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
dialogo.show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o LayoutInflater para pegar uma View que representa seu arquivo xml.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null, false);
```

A partir da view, pegue as instancias de seus EditText e do Button:

```
EditText edtText= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Se precisar usar o LinearLayout, atribua um id a ele e pegue a instancia como demonstrado acima. Por fim, adicione a View em seu Dialog:

```
 dialogo.setView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assim funcionou bem

```
public void Dialog() {

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_esqueci_senha, null, false);
    final EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.et_dialog_esqueci_senha_email);
    builder.setView(view)

            .setPositiveButton("Enviar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+editText.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            });
    builder.show();
}
```